# W in transcript

Tags: grades

I am in second year of Master course in physics.

In the 2nd semester, I took a course in material science dept. called Solid State Physics, but then I dropped it because I took other Solid State Physics course in Energy dept, because the new course is more appropriate for me, as I'm working in the field of theoretical solid state physics. But, since I have dropped the 1st one, at the end of semester there, the course trace is still within my transcript with 'W' grade, while I got a A- for the other course. Although W is not affecting my GPA, is there disadvantage of W when I find a job or Ph.D admission?

Comment: One W in your whole transcript?  Probably no disadvantage.

Comment: A **WF** (if your school has it, "withdraw while failing") might, but I pretty much expect to see every student have a *W* at some point in their career.